# how to pass domain name to backend with pound

Tags: varnish, pound

I am using pound as a way to decode SSL for the backend, but the bulk of the work is done on varnish (including virtualhost stuff). As a result, I need pound to just forward all other traffic to varnish verbatim, but it doesn't seem to do that.

I am using the default configuration:

```
ListenHTTP
    Address 1.2.3.4
    Port    8080

    ## allow PUT and DELETE also (by default only GET, POST and HEAD)?:
    xHTTP           0

    Service
            BackEnd
                    Address 127.0.0.1
                    Port    80
            End
    End
End
```

So whenever I hit example.com:8080, it will always redirect to the default backend for varnish, which i assume was because the domain (host) header isn't send along. Anyone know what could be wrong?

Thanks a lot!

Jason

Answer (score 0):

In the configuration that you have posted the SSL part is missing. Something like (look at the first and fourth line)

```
ListenHTTPS
    Address 1.2.3.4
    Port    8080
    Cert "/etc/ssl/myverynicesitecertificate.pem"

    ## allow PUT and DELETE also (by default only GET, POST and HEAD)?:
    xHTTP           0

    Service
            BackEnd
                    Address 127.0.0.1
                    Port    80
            End
    End
End
```